# Libgdx, implementing unit scale into rendering object layers

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently making a 2D game with the `Libgdx` framework, while learning it. I understand most things, but i am running into a problem when rendering maps. I can rendered `tile layers` fine, as it is handled completely by the built in classes (`OrthogonalMapRenderer`). However i am running into a problem when trying to render object layers. As a default implmenetation doesn't exist, i have to create my own. The simplest form i made is this:

```
    @Override
    public void renderObject(MapObject object){
        if(object instanceof TextureMapObject){
            TextureMapObject curObject = (TextureMapObject) object;
            batch.draw(curObject.getTextureRegion(),curObject.getOriginX(),curObject.getOriginY());
        }
    }
```

This draws the object, but not in the right scale. Now the `OrthogonalMapRenderer` takes `unitScale` as a parameter, so you can work with arbitrary units. What i am wondering is, how i would implement `unitScale` into my own renderObject method. I tried looking through the `OrthogonalMapRenderer` class to find a solution, but it is extremely confusing. I would appreciate help.

Thank you in advance!